# External react file not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In `index.html` I have:

```
<div class="header-content-inner" id="example">
    ...
</div>
```

And then:

```
<script src="js/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="js/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="js/segui-info.jsx"></script>
```

This "segui-info" is the external js file with react code in it:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var ex = <h1>It worked!</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(ex, document.getElementById("example"));
```

As you can guess, the "ex" is not being appended / rendered to that div. I'm a beginner to react and I'm failing to understand why it's not working. In simple examples [just like this one](https://gist.github.com/mdolon/10854b1140ea72a7f83ebec6b67f73dc) they use react code inside a `<script>` tag. I don't want to use all the react code inside a .html file. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is what I get on the console:

[image]

Comment: do you have any errors in the console?, I do not think "import" works because it requires to be transpiled, and as your importing react-dom and react as external files, those files exposed global variables React and  ReactDOM so I guess, there is no need to use import

Comment: check this little example https://jsbin.com/laqiribeze/edit?html,js,output, notice that the js tab is set to ES6/babel, so my code is transpiled

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the console errors to the post. I've also tried to remove the imports, it did not work.

Comment: How that babel tab code is linked to the HTML, there's no <script> link.

Comment: that tab is just an entry point for users to insert code, in the backend JSbin grabs the code I wrote compiles it and then displays it the output tab (which is an iframe)

Comment: I use JSBIN, only for testing purposes, if you want to write JSX, better just setup a dev environment using webpack, which will do all the work for you!

Comment: [I found the answer to the problem here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/1795924) require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove import statements from code.

In your script first add 'react' and then add 'react-dom'. It will definitely work!

Below is the simple working example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="ext.jsx"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="example"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In ext.jsx will have

```
var ex = <h1>It worked!</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(ex, document.getElementById('example'));
```

You can run the same code snippet on 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19omL0yr/)

Comment: When I do this, I get the following error on the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined`. It can't find ReactDOM because it's not being imported, and when I import, it says that "require" is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

In react you use functions to return JSX, in your example `var ex = <h1>It worked!</h1>;` is probably typecasting to just a string, rather you need to make it a function that returns the code you want.  Try this below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const ex = () => (
    <h1>It worked!</h1>;
);    

ReactDOM.render(ex, document.getElementById("example"));
```

Comment: I did that, I continue getting the error. The problem is probably somewhere else, on the linking part or whatever.

Comment: @melmquist this won't work - your example creates a simple React component, but `ReactDOM.render()` expects an element.